# Include framework into xcode C++ project - linker error

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, linker

I'm trying to use **libpng** for reading data from image file in my c++ project, making on xcode and have some problems to include it.

So, I've make the next steps:

1. download **libpng** sources from http://libpng.sourceforge.net (version 1.6.29) and unarchive
2. download xcode project folder from here https://github.com/IGRSoft/libpng-xcode-project and put it into **./projects** folder
3. open libpng.xcodeproj and make build. As a result I have */Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/libpng-efgdtopqjltxorcwlnlvdirxqclm/Build/Products/Debug/**libpng.framework***
4. I copied this file to my xcode project folder
5. Add this file to **Project->General->Linked Frameworks and Libraries**

Then, when I'm trying to compile project, I have an error:

`ld: framework not found libpng
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

What I'm doing wrong or what step was missed?

I'm new in xcode so be patient and give a detailed answer, please.

Comment: click the framework and add to the project on the right side of the File Inspector Check Mark  Target Membership.

Comment: Yes, I think it already been correct: http://image.prntscr.com/image/cec04de5df2c4795bb82c204438afb83.jpeg and doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

the error of library not found usually referrers to setting header search path wrong so go to build setting/header search path
then add $(inherit)

Comment: Like this: http://image.prntscr.com/image/32b722e8aa254e4d92e00c96d5a0a69b.jpeg ? It doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Now I found solution.

I moved framework file from project folder to folder with .xcodeproj and it linked successfull:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SB4F.png)

But there is **another one error** on starting program:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @loader_path/../Frameworks/libpng.framework/Versions/A/libpng
Referenced from: /Users/admin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B875D4BF-EE6B-4601-9DFC-9C534AD6C085/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/981ECC6B-5EDB-4646-A990-510FEB619650/Happy Ball.app/Happy Ball
Reason: image not found
```

Comment: Trying to add my framework to **Embedded Binaries**: http://image.prntscr.com/image/6adb08bdbf604310a962038ba6fa6487.jpeg - but have **Failed to load** after **Successfull Compiling**: http://image.prntscr.com/image/57820a3869884f1a8d6acd92256f1086.jpeg